# OpenVPN doesn't start correctly

Tags: vpn, vps, openvpn

When I install Open VPN and try to start it, I get this:

```
iptables service not started because of error (SVC_RUN_EXCEPT)
```

I have VPS in OVH. I don´t know if the problem can be tun/tap ppp.

I also don´t know which is the real issue, if the problem is from OVH or something else. Has anyone else installed Open VPN without this error?

Comment: Welcome to SF. Please conduct some debugging of your own and show your effort, so that your peers can give you more pointed advice. As it stands, your question is rather too broad.

Answer (score 3):

Your VPS does not support iptables, you will have to get your host to enable it for you. Alternatively get a VPS based on KVM or similar rather than containers like OpenVZ.

Comment: My server has KVM and based in OpenVZ Container , regards

Comment: Have you some idea about this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK iptables connection tracking and tun/tap modules is disabled by default on OVH VPS. You can email to OVH support about this issue. Unfortunately without configuration from hosting provider side you can't solve this issue.